# Can I search for online users matching my languages on Busuu?

Tags: busuu

On Busuu.com, it's possible to find users with the right languages and users that are online.

Can I somehow see the intersection of those sets?

Answer (score 1):

Well, Busuu.com is not meant to meet new people of the same language/interest or anything like that and so there is no way you can do it.